# Filtering a List using lambda

Tags: c#, list, lambda

I have an object which has properties ID, brandID, brandName, NumPages, and Type.

i need to show the top 5 brands by numPage size, a brand may have multiple IDs, so I need to group by brand

```
 listing.OrderByDescending(o => o.numPage).GroupBy(o=> o.brandName).Take(5).ToList();
```

is alone the lines of what im looking for but this is not valid code.

Comment: Why it is not being valid? Are you getting an error message or just not getting the wanted results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like a given brand name may have several ID's and that you want the top 5 brand's sorted by numPage.  Is that correct

If so try the following

```
var query = listing
  .GroupBy(x => x.brandName)
  .OrderByDescending(brands => brands.Sum(x => x.numPage))
  .Select(x => x.Key)
  .Take(5);
```

Note: After the `GroupBy` operation you're now passing around a collection of the brand objects instead of single ones.  Hence to order by the `numPage` we need to sum it for all of the brand objects in the group.  The `.Select(x => x.Key)` will select back out the original `brandName` on which the group is based

Comment: An `IGrouping` doesn't have a `numPage` member, so that shouldn't compile.

Comment: @hvd I verified in Visual Studio that this compiles. One of my earlier versions had a typo but the current one should work

Comment: Yes, my comment was based on the `.OrderByDescending(x => x.numPage.Sum())` which you've indeed fixed.

Comment: @hvd i think i get bitten by that mistake every time I hand role a groupby :(

Comment: i get an Arguement null exection and it's not valid code, 
I should mention instead of a var query, im doing this in a viewModel being called from return View(new viewModel(listing.GroupBy... but that shouldn't make a difference

Comment: @tapius this code runs fine on my local machine.  Where are you getting the `ArgumentNullException` from?  The only thing that comes to mind is either `listing` or possible `brandName` was null on a particular instance

Comment: hmm, sorry im getting:

Argument 1: cannot convert from 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<System.Linq.IGrouping<int,Project.Web.Models.AdListing>>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<Project.Web.Models.AdListing>'

Comment: @tapius it looks like `listing` may already have a grouping applied to it based on `brandId`.  You can flatten the list again by `var listing2 = listing.SelectMany(x => x.);`

Comment: sorry, im confused still.

 var query = listing.GroupBy(o => o.brandId)
                                              .OrderByDescending(brand => brand.Sum(o => o.numPages))
                                              .Take(5);

                var listing2 = query.SelectMany(o => o);
return View(new AdViewModel(listing2));

its returning more than 5, and they dont have the highest numPages

Comment: @tapius could you put the type of everything into your question? In particular that of `listing`?

Comment: List<AdListing> listing = new List<AdListing>();

Comment: @tapius but what's the definition for `AdListing`?

Comment: AdViewModel:
public AdViewModel(IEnumerable<AdListing> listing)
        {
            Listing = listing;
        }
        public IEnumerable<AdListing> Listing
        {
        get; private set;
        }

Comment: public class AdListing
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public int brandId { get; set; }
        public decimal numPages { get; set; }
        public string brandName { get; set; }
        public string type { get; set; }

    }

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/6711/discussion-between-tapius-and-jaredpar)

Answer (score 0):

just tried and it works:

```
public class Listing
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public int BrandID { get; set; }
    public string BrandName { get; set; }
    public int NumPages { get; set; }
    public Type Type { get; set; }    
}
```

Here the filtering

```
Listing listing1 = new Listing() { NumPages = 2, BrandName = "xx" };
Listing listing2 = new Listing() { NumPages = 2, BrandName = "xx" };
Listing listing3 = new Listing() { NumPages = 2, BrandName = "xx" };
Listing listing4 = new Listing() { NumPages = 3, BrandName = "xxxxx" };

List<Listing> allListings = new List<Listing>() { listing1, listing2, listing3, listing4 };

var result = allListings.OrderByDescending(x => x.NumPages).GroupBy(x => x.BrandName).Take(5);
```